# Ошибка при логинизации Django REST

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, login

у меня есть стандартное api для входа, но почему-то начала возникать ошибка связанная с неправильным ключом, ничего в коде не менял и не трогал, вот ошибка:

```
 raise CookieError('Illegal key %r' % (key,))
http.cookies.CookieError: Illegal key 'refresh_tokenЧ%'
HTTP POST /api/login/ 500 [0.30, 127.0.0.1:54208]
```

Comment: 'refresh_tokenЧ%' - тут действительно должна быть буква "Ч"?